# Inferring parameters for a regression with features of both multivariate probit and ordinal regression?

Tags: bayesian, ordered-logit, choice-modeling, approximate-bayesian-computation, ordered-probit

Based on my data generated by a complex process and the problem below detailed, I have tried various approaches, to no avail.

**I am trying to answer one or more of the following questions:**

a) Has someone solved my problem already? Are there other clever
   approaches I could use instead (perhaps something like PLS or CCA)?

b) What is the right literature to look for previous work addressing
   my problem?

c) If this problem is novel (which I personally doubt), what is the
   right approach to solve it?

d) In my proposed approach below described, is there something
   obvious I am missing?

**Here is my problem:**

For $N$ individuals, with $M$ associated covariates, I observe outcomes in $J$ possible classes; thus my design matrix $X$ is of dimension $M$ x $N$ and my response matrix $Y$ is of dimension $N \times J$. For a given class $j$ there is a latent variable $U_{i,j}$ s.t. when $U_{i,j} < 0$, $Y_{i,j}=0$ and $Y_{i,j}=1$, otherwise . Up to this point, if $U \sim MVN(\beta X, \Sigma)$, I have described a standard multivariate probit regression scenario. However, if a given $U_{i,j}$ is greater than all other classes $U_{i,-j}$ *and* greater than some constant $c_1$, then $Y_{i,j} =t$ if $c_{t-1} < U_{i,j} < c_t$ where $t\in \{1,2,...,T-1\}$; $Y_{i,j}=T$ if $U_{i,j} > c_{T-1}$. Here the cutpoints $c_t$ are unknown. On its own, the latter half corresponds to an ordinal regression problem. However, together this problem seems to be more complex than either probit or ordinal regression.

**Below is the R code to generate data from this process.**

The values of $U$ are generated directly without specifying a linear relationship with $X$:

```
library(MASS) # for mvrnorm

N <- 1e3 # num. of observations
J <- 12  # num. of classes
cuts <- c(1.5, 2, 2.25, 2.5, 2.7, 3) # T=6

S <- rWishart(n=1, Sigma=diag(J), df=20) # sample cov. mat.
U <- mvrnorm(n=N, mu=rep(0, J), Sigma=S[,,1]) # generate U
Y <- apply(U, 1, function(u) { # generate Y from U
     u <- as.numeric(scale(u)) # s.d. is 1 for identifiability
     y <- ifelse(u < 0, 0, 1)  # U's extreme enough are observed
     cond <- u > cuts[1] & u == max(u) # most extreme U's are ranked
     if(any(cond)) 
       y[which(cond)] <- findInterval(u[which(cond)], cuts)
     return(y)
  }
)
```

In my case, $N$ is approximately $3500$, $J=12$ and $M=30$, and $T=6$. The outcomes of the classes are correlated and the individuals are hierarchically related.

**Here are the solutions I have tried so far:**

Initially, I thought I could use JAGS to solve this problem. Before implementing the full model, I tried a hierarchical multivariate probit regression. However, JAGS seemed to take an inordinately long time to sample from the posterior.

Thus, I have since been searching through the simulated likelihood literature e.g. GHK, but found no work reproducing the model described above. Specifically, I am exploring approaches such as approximate Bayesian computation (ABC), indirect inference, and simulated method of moments.

Any help would therefore be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need the notion of a latent class?  It is very general and may be confusing you.  Also GLMMs are notorious for having bad mixing - it really depends on how you set up the sampler.  BayesX and INLA may be better tools than jags.

Comment: What is the alternative to a latent class when dealing with ordinal data? Wouldn't I lose power by not modeling the hidden process underlying the observed data?

Comment: Only example is to model $ Pr (Y> y) $.  and make this an increasing/decreasing function of $ y $.  I think this is what is done in hazard/survival modelling.

Comment: If it really only is an issue of sampling speed, then Stan might be an alternative.

Comment: By the way, just to make sure I understand your problem correctly, let me phrase it in my own words: you want to estimate an ordered probit, and the complication is that you have several outcomes, so that the ordered probit becomes a multivariate ordered probit. Does this sum up your problem? I am asking because it sounds like that to me, but it seems that there are papers out there dealing with multivariate ordered probits, so I conclude I must misinterpret sth...

Comment: @coffeinjunky It is almost a multivariate ordered probit. *Except* for the fact that when for some class $j$ where $U_{i,j} > U_{i,-j}$ *i.e.* greater than all other U's for an individual, then the rank is observed, but only for that given class $j$. See the lines in the simulation source code regarding the variable *cond* for clarification. The simulation is a multivariate probit before those lines.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into the stats literature on reduced-rank vector generalized linear models? It seems you might be trying to identify the model by introducing constraints that in effect make it a hybrid of the probit and ordinal regressions, plus with a multilevel structure on the right-hand side of the equation. [This](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~yee/VGAM/doc/rrvglm.pdf) document (pdf alert) on the VGAM package in R offers a relatively straightforward introduction to reduced-rank generalized models.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. While it looks like *rrvglm()* is along the lines of what I need, VGAM only implements a bivariate logit/probit model and it's not clear to me how I could use constraints to coax a multinomial logit model into a multivariate logit.